# Divs Alignment - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a block of blogs by looping all blogs like below

```
<div class="row">
   // loop Start - foreach blog in blogs
      <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">// Content</div>
      <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
   // loop End
</div>
```

When I run the loop it give following output

[image]

Which shows following result (forget the background image for now). I was expecting that the 3rd blog should be placed exactly below the first one.

[image]

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: I'm not sure why did you place `col-lg-1` to your loop.

Comment: Plus, why not upgrading to bootstrap 4?

Comment: `col-lg-1` is used to give enough spaces between blogs. Right now I can't upgrade to v4.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code and let me know if that helps

```
<div class="row">
 // loop Start - foreach blog in blogs
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
     <div class="col-xs-12">// Content</div>
  </div>
  //// end row ////
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
     <div class="col-xs-12">// Content</div>
  </div>
  //// end row ////
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
     <div class="col-xs-12">// Content</div>
  </div>
   // loop End
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't think so that I can do this. I have to loop using `foreach`

Comment: I know that , it's render after the foreach, you should use one of that in the foreach and run it